# Run a program every time a file is changed

Tags: mysql, linux, daemon, squid

Ok, this is what I want to do. I have a squid proxy setup on my webserver (which is running openSuSE 11.1) and every time a new entry is added to access.log, I want to dump the access information to a MySQL database. What is the best approach for me to do this?

Currently, I'm thinking of writing a daemon that checks for changes to the file like every 2-3 seconds, but I don't think that's a very efficient approach. In what other way could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found, which is extremely specific to my requirement is use a 'redirect_program' for Squid: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors

This works perfectly for my purpose and gives me just enough information in the program to do my thing.

Thanks to paulsm4 for a perfect solution in case such a feature is not available.

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at iNotify:

http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have squid log directly into the database, or have a (continously running) daemon which (notionally) does "tail -f" on the log file, inserting records.

Depending on how much data loss you can tolerate, you may need to do lots of tricks remembering the "point" in the file you had reached in a durable way (say a small table in the database, which you write to in the same transaction) etc. It is nontrivial to correctly do this, however, it can be done.

Normally you'd want to do this asynchronously as squid is likely to create records in the file faster than mysql can take them, especially when it's offilne.

You'll also want to batch the records, as inserting a single record is relatively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will work but perhaps you can create a table with the **[CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html)** and have the squid proxy writing directly into the created `table.CSV` file instead of the `access.log` one.